# How to connect PostgreSQL to web2py?

Tags: postgresql, web2py

How do I connect a postgresql to a web2py application? The web2py documetation says that I can connect it using the command `db = DAL("postgres://myuser:mypassword@localhost:5432/mydb")` but upon doing it, it produces an error saying `RuntimeError: No driver of supported ones ('psycopg2',) is available`.

I already installed psycopg2 but I don't know how to use it in the web2py app. There are not a lot of resources out there about this so I'm having a lot of trouble.

Comment: Are you running the Windows or MacOS binary of web2py? If so, switch to the source code version.

Comment: @Anthony yes, i'm using the source code version since I'm using a linux machine

Comment: If you have psycopg2 installed properly within the same version of Python that is running web2py, it should be available to web2py. Maybe try starting a web2py shell (`python web2py.py -S appname -M`) and see if you can directly import psycopg2 from within the shell.

Comment: @Anthony I already installed the psycopg2 in the modules folder of my app so it's fine now. But when I'm trying to establish a connection to postgres through psycopg2, it produces this error: `KeyError: 'psycopg2.extensions'`. What's wrong with my setup?

Answer (score 1):

Your DAL code is correct. I think psycopg2 is not installed correctly.
Maybe you want to install `psycopg2-binary`.

Comment: I've already installed the `psycopg2-binary` library, but I don't know how to set it up on my web2py app. And whenever I import it, it produces an error: `ImportError: No module named applications.test.modules.psycopg2`. What should I do for the web2py to have access to this library?

Comment: You might want to delete all current files in your database(after backing up somewhere) then see what happens.